# Caddy TLS handshake error

Tags: caddy

Simple caddy config

```
www.example.ga {
    proxy / http://server:12345
}

example.ga {
    proxy / http://server:12345
}
```

but have infinite count of errors like

```
92.53.91.128 - No such site at :443 (Remote: 72.210.252.137, Referer: )
TLS handshake error from 68.195.148.47:54875: tls: client offered an unsupported, maximum protocol version of 300
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That just means that old clients that don't support modern versions of TLS are trying to connect to your server; usually bots. [Version 300 is SSL 3.0](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#pkg-constants), which Caddy does not support because it is old and broken. You can generally ignore these log messages.